# Technique to identify radical ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals, radicals

I am studying algebraic geometry and I would like to know some technique to identify radical ideals. For instance, how do I know if the ideal $I=(x-4,y^2-x)$ is radical?

Comment: There are algorithms that compute the radical, based on Groebner basis. You can find a reference to the original work in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146099/generators-for-the-radical-of-an-ideal, and an explanation of that in the book by David A. Cox, John Little, Donal O’Shea.

Comment: You can also compute the quotient of your ring by this ideal and show it has no nilpotents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideal is $(x-4,y^2-4)=(x-4,(y-2)(y+2))$. It is contained in $(x-4,y-2)$ and $(x-4,y+2)$, both of which are prime — they are even maximal --- and equals their intersection. It follows that your ideal is radical.

Comment: Hello, really in the ideal $y^2-x$ appears instead of $y^2-4$... the same idea can work?

Comment: $y^2-4=(y^2-x)+(x-4)$...

Comment: I understand your argument, but, how do you know that $(x-4, y-2)$ and $(x-4, y+2)$ are prime?

Comment: As I wrote, they are maximal.